# Select where in em LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, select

Como converter o código `select` abaixo em LINQ?

```
select * from producao
where id not in
(select idProducao from bpi)
```

Comment: Italo, eu respodi ontem uma bem parecida com essa sua pergunta
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/186100/5846

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
producao.Where(p=>!bpi.Select(p=>p.idProducao).ToList().Contains(id))
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
db.Producao.Where(p => !db.Bpi.Select(b => b.idProducao).Contains(c.Id));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/EntityFramework/NotContainsInAnotherTable.cs).