# Como usar o método Contains em uma pesquisa utilizando o EntityFramework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, query

Estou tentando fazer a seguinte consulta **sql**, utilizando o [EntityFramework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/entity-framework):

```
select * from pedidos
where pedidoID not in (select pedidoID from agendamentos);
```

Eu realizei umas pesquisas e descobri que o método do [EntityFramework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/entity-framework) que substitui o `not in` do **sql** é o `Contains()`.
Então montei o seguinte código:

```
var pedidos = Db.Pedidos.Where(x =>
                    Db.Pedidos.Where(y => y.PedidoId == x.Agendamentos.Select(z=>z.PedidoId).
                    FirstOrDefault()).Select(y => y.PedidoId).ToList().
                    Contains(
                        Db.Pedidos.Where(z=>z.PedidoId == x.PedidoId).
                        Select(y => y.PedidoId).FirstOrDefault())
                    ).
                    ToPagedList(1, RecordsPerPage);
```

Com o método Contains eu recebo o seguinte erro:
[image: Error Message]

Acredito que por ser um *requested timeout*, a pesquisa **sql** está demorando muito para ser executada, então tentei colocar condições para diminuir o tamanho da listagem, e mesmo assim continuo dando o mesmo erro.

Assim a função funciona perfeitamente:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se puderem me ajudar neste problema, ficarei grato!

Comment: Você não alterou a configuração que define o tempo de *timeout*?

Comment: Não alterei, ela está padrão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

João, uma forma mais prática de fazer o que você está tentando fazer é usando o [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx)

um exemplo seria:

```
var pedidos1 = db.Pedidos
                    .Where(a => !a.Agendamentos.Any());
```

O `SQL` gerado foi o seguinte

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[PedidoId] AS [PedidoId]
    FROM [dbo].[Pedidoes] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[Agendamentoes] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE [Extent1].[PedidoId] = [Extent2].[PedidoId]
    )
```

Não é um `NOT IN` mas o resultado será o mesmo

No entanto, seu modelo tem que ter as propriedades de navegação entre as entidades

```
public class Pedido
{
    public int PedidoId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Agendamento> Agendamentos { get; set; }
}

public class Agendamento
{
    public int AgendamentoId { get; set; }
    public int PedidoId { get; set; }
    public virtual Pedido Pedido { get; set; }
}
```

Usando o `Contains`:

```
var pedidos2 = db.Pedidos.Where(pedido => !db.Agendamentos.Select(agendamento => agendamento.PedidoId).Contains(pedido.PedidoId));
```

O `SQL` gerado foi exatemente o mesmo.

A forma de conseguir um `NOT IN` seria primeiramente guardar todos os Id de pedido que estão em agendamento e depois realizar a consulta usando o `Contains`

```
var agendamentos = db.Agendamentos.Select(a => a.PedidoId).ToList();
var pedidos3 = db.Pedidos.Where(pedido => !agendamentos.Contains(pedido.PedidoId));
```

O `SQL` gerado ficou:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[PedidoId] AS [PedidoId]
    FROM [dbo].[Pedidoes] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE  NOT ([Extent1].[PedidoId] IN (1, 2))
```

Comment: Deu certo, Obrigado! Não sabia que era possível utilizar o método any para resolver isso!