# Como utilizar expressão Lambda em List<List<object>>?

Tags: c#

Boa tarde estou de desenvolvendo uma aplicação, que retorna uma lista de lista de itens de notas, porém, preciso preencher algumas campos com os valores de cada lista de itens por vez, porém, não estou conseguindo implementar o método Select() ou Where() do objeto lista ?

Método que preenche a lista:

```
public List<List<ItNota>> SelecionaDadosItNota(out String pstrMsg, out Boolean   pbooRetorno, Util.ObjTransf pobjTransf, List<Cliente> plstCliente)
{
    List<List<ItNota>> lstListItNota = default(List<List<ItNota>>);

    SqlConnection conn = ConexaoBD.CriarConexao(out pstrMsg, out pbooRetorno);

    if (pbooRetorno)
    {
        using (conn)
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("uspCtzSelectDadosProd", conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cd_emp", null);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nu_rom", null);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cd_clien", null);

                try
                {
                    lstListItNota = new List<List<ItNota>>();

                    foreach (var cliente in plstCliente)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters["@cd_emp"].Value = pobjTransf.CdEmp;
                        cmd.Parameters["@nu_rom"].Value = pobjTransf.NuRom;
                        cmd.Parameters["@cd_clien"].Value = cliente.CdClien;

                        using (SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            if (rd.HasRows)
                            {
                                List<ItNota> lstItNota = new List<ItNota>();

                                while (rd.Read())
                                {
                                    ItNota itNota = new ItNota();

                                     itNota.CdClien = cliente.CdClien;
                                     itNota.Seq = rd["seq"].ToString();
                                     itNota.Codigo = rd["codigo"].ToString();
                                     itNota.Descricao = rd["descricao"].ToString();
                                     itNota.Valor = rd["valor"].ToString();
                                     itNota.Nf = rd["nf"].ToString();
                                     itNota.Perecivel = rd["perecivel"].ToString();
                                     itNota.Embarcador = rd["embarcador"].ToString();

                                     lstItNota.Add(itNota);
                                }
                                lstListItNota.Add(lstItNota);
                            }
                            pbooRetorno = true;
                        }                                
                    }
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    pstrMsg = ex.Message;
                    pbooRetorno = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    return lstListItNota;
}

// Busca os dados dos itens da nota
List<List<ItNota>> lstListItNota = seleciona.SelecionaDadosItNota(out pstrMsg, out pbooRetorno, pobjTransf, lstCliente);
```

Alguém me ajudar a pegar um item por vez sem um Foreach ?

Comment: Qual o resultado que espera obter e qual está obtendo? Tem erro? Qual? Onde quer fazer isto que pede?

Comment: Você quer algo do tipo `lstListItNota.Where(a => a.Any(b => b.Codigo == "A")).ToList();`?

Comment: @bigown, na verdade não estava conseguindo implementar a busca mesmo.

Comment: @PabloVargas, isso mesmo. Consegui fazer da seguinte forma: var lstListItNota = plstListItNota.Where(x => x.Exists(y => y.CdClien == cliente.CdClien)); - Porém ainda tem que criar dois loop Foreach para pegar obter o resultado que espero.

Comment: Ainda não entendi bem o que quer, mas me parece que só seria uma boa ideia se reestruturar bastante esse código, e olhe lá.

Comment: @bigown, acredito que você tenha uma forma melhor de fazer de acordo com o seu conhecimento, porém, não vejo outra forma de fazer. Qual seria a melhor maneira de estrutura o código ?

Comment: @PabloVargas, o código que você escreveu funcionou, era isso mesmo que eu precisava. Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente o que você precisa é fazer um `Where` na sua `lstListItNota` e fazendo as condições no `Any`:

```
lstListItNota.Where(a => a.Any(b => b.Codigo == "A")).ToList();
```

Comment: Utilizando o Exists() no lugar do método Any() também funcionou. Mas, deixei com Any() mesmo.

Comment: Eu respondi uma pergunta sobre o uso do Contains esses dias, não cheguei a usar o Exists nos exemplos http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/186100/5846

Comment: Dei uma olha nesse post e usar EntityFramework ajuda muito. Porém, vou ter que aprender a utilizar, porque ainda não tenho esse conhecimento.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, tente o seguinte:

```
lstListItNota.SelectMany(lista => lista).Where(item => item.Codigo == "A")).ToList();
```

O select many retorna uma coleção de coleções, ou seja, você tem uma lista com várias listas que armazenam o mesmo tipo de objetos, o **SelectMany** irá te retornar uma coleção desses objetos, não mais de listas dos mesmos.

Ai então você será capaz de utilizar os demais métodos de extensão como os faz usualmente.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: da forma forma que o Pablo havia falado consegui resolver meu problema. Fiz um novo teste com o código que você passou para conhecer outra forma de fazer, porém, não é retornado valor, a coleção está vindo vazia.

Comment: @DiegoFarias você pode postar seu código é uma pequena massa de dados para analisarmos melhor?

Answer (score 0):

Poderia fazer assim

```
List<ItNota> lista = conn.TABELA.Select(x=> new ItNota() {CdClien  = x.CdClien}).ToList();
```

Assim você retornaria uma lista do tipo ItNota(), utilizando o Entity Framework.

E para realizar o foreach seria assim

```
foreach (ItNota item in lista){

}
```

Comment: Hebert, acredito que nesse caso esse código não serviria para o meu cenário, porque tenho um roteiro com n clientes, e para cada cliente tem n notas. Eu criei uma List<List<ItNota>> para agrupar todas as notas de cada cliente, e depois extrair cada List<ItNota> de cada cliente.

Comment: Como está no banco essa estrutura? Outra tabela?

Comment: Da forma que o Pablo mostrou acima já resolveu o problema Herbert, obrigado.